# Auto generate table id

Tags: sql, postgresql, jpa, postgresql-9.1

I use this SQL query to generate test data into table:

```
INSERT into onboarding_tasks SELECT generate_series(1,10) AS id,
    ('ABC name ' || generate_series(1,10)) AS business_name;
```

As you can see the id range numbers are fixed and I get duplicate if error. How this SQL query can be edited in a way that database will auto-generate id?

With Hibernate I use this code to create id:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, updatable = false, nullable = false)
private Long id;
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.1 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: Yes, I will update it.

Answer (score 0):

You would define the table first:

```
create table onboarding_tasks (
    id int generated always as identity,
    business_name text
);

INSERT into onboarding_tasks (business_name)
    SELECT ('ABC name ' || generate_series(1,10)) AS business_name;
```

Comment: I added the Entity code used to create the table. Do you know it correct?